# Python Pillow ValueError: images do not match

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am currently working on a script, that pastes images over another to randomly generate a pixel character. The randomness code is already done and I moved to creating the pictures. Now I face the earlyest problem. When I tried this code:

```
from PIL import Image

basebg = Image.open("./among us assets/BaseBackground.png").convert("RGBA")
img1 = Image.open("./among us assets/charmodels/character1.png").convert("RGBA")

print(basebg.size)
print(basebg.mode)
print(img1.size)
print(img1.mode)

# intermediate = Image.alpha_composite(basebg, img1)

basebg.paste(img1, (0, 0, 0, 0))
```

an error accured:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): <br>
  File "c:\[...]\blabla.py", line 67, in <module> <br>
    basebg.paste(img1, (0, 0, 0, 0)) <br>
  File "[...]\Image.py", line 1527, in paste <br>
    self.im.paste(im, box) <br>
ValueError: images do not match <br>
```

The proportions are: basebg = 300x300, img1 = 150x192 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are trying to paste a 150 by 192 pixel image into a rectangle that measures zero by zero pixels.  There is no need to pass a 4-element tuple there, you can just use two elements to specify the left and top coordinates.

Comment: What's a *"pixel character"* please? Why do you use `./among us assets/charmodels/character1.png` - what's wrong with `among us assets/charmodels/character1.png`? Why are you adding an alpha layer to your solid background image - do you want the final result to be partially transparent?

Comment: I dont want the result to be transperent. I want the transperent one to be placed above the background.

Comment: Also, the size of the objects placed on the background variates. So I cant give it a box, bc it would stretch the objects.

Answer (score 1):

remove (0 , 0 )

```
from PIL import Image

basebg = Image.open("banner.jpg").convert("RGBA")
img1 = Image.open("demo.png").convert("RGBA")

print(basebg.size)
print(basebg.mode)
print(img1.size)
print(img1.mode)

# intermediate = Image.alpha_composite(basebg, img1)

basebg.paste(img1, (0, 0, ))
basebg.save("filename.png")
basebg.show("filename.png")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).